# Avoiding instability and missing boundary condition errors when solving a system of 3 differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve this system of equations:

```
dw(v,t)/dt =2g(v,t) w(t,v)
g(t,v)= Pi/2 (v^2)d g0(v,t)/dt
d go(v,t)/dt + d/dv[dw/dt *1/v^3)]=0
```

with initial conditions:

```
f0= (a/(Pi)^0.5)*e^[v^2/ve^2] + (b/(Pi)^0.5)*e^[(v - u)^2/ve^2]
a^2 + b^2 = 1
f0=go(v,0)
w(v,0)=0
```

This is my code

Here I am initializing some variables and defining f0 that is g(v,t=0).

```
a = 0.5;
b = (3^0.5)/2;
ve = 1;
u = 1;
f0[v_] = (a/(Pi)^0.5)Exp[v^2/ve^2] + (b/(Pi)^0.5)Exp[(v - u)^2/ve^2];
u1 = Log[((1 - a^2)/a^2)^0.5]/(2*u) + u/2;
u2 = 3u/2 - Log[((1 - a^2)/a^2)^0.5]/(2u);
f0[u1]
f0[u2]
```

Here I am using a system of 3 eqs for 3 functions and equating g(v,0)=f0

```
sol = NDSolve[{
    D[go[v, t], t] + D[D[w[v, t], t], v]/(v^3) + (-3v^(-4))D[w[v, t], t] == 0,
    g[v, t] == Pi/2 (v^2) D[go[v, t], v],
    go[v, 0] == f0[v],
    D[w[v, t], t] == 2g[v, t]w[v, t],
    w[v, 0] == 0},
    {go[v, t], W[v, t]}, 
    {v, u1, u2},
    {t, 0, 10000000000}]
```

And it is returning errors like

> The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help

> No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue was specified for
> {g}; the result may not be unique

Comment: The code contains several errors.  There are no boundary conditions, which probably is the source of the second warning message.  The limits of integraton in `v` are not specified.  One of the variables in the code probably should be `go` instead of `g`.  Note also that the second PDE can be solved symbolically up to a function of `t` only, which may allow the other two equations to be simplified.

Comment: The limits of integration of v are specified. They are u1 and u2.

u1 = Log[((1 - a^2)/a^2)^0.5]/(2*u) + u/2;
u2 = 3u/2 - Log[((1 - a^2)/a^2)^0.5]/(2u);

and go is a variable in the code...

Comment: Cross-posted: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2432445